# Add stroke to internal lines in mesh objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, gradient-mesh

I am trying to create a fishing net in adobe illustrator. I have created an ellipse object and created the mesh but adding a stroke via the appearance panel only does it to the border of the mesh object not the internal lines (see the picture below). How can I add a stroke to the internal lines to create a net appearance? If this is not possible with the mesh tool how would you create a net in illustrator? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mesh lines are not actual paths. You can not stroke them like other paths. Mesh lines are for *construction*.

If you wish to have a grid of lines, you need to create that grid. Then you could use a mesh to transform, distort, and otherwise alter the grid. The easiest way to create a grid of lines is by using the **Rectangular Grid Tool**.

[image]

**While dragging** with that tool the **up, down, left,** and **right arrow keys** will increase/decrease the amount of grid sections.

[image]